# Number of Paths on a 2D Grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, inclusion-exclusion

Given the points $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$. How many self avoiding paths of length $L$ exist between them. I do not think an exact closed form answer exists for this. However, one could make an asymptotic bound like $O(4^L)$. Can we do better than this? For example, $(0,0)$ to $(0,5)$ has 1 length of length 5.

Comment: If the 2D grid is unbounded, there are an infinite number of solutions. Are you looking for [A064297](https://oeis.org/A064297)?

Comment: what does self avoiding mean?

Comment: The number of paths is not unbounded. There is a trivial upper bound of $4^L$. There are $L$ moves and $4$ options for each move.

Comment: Self avoiding means the path has no loops.

Comment: is the path continuous or discrete?

Comment: It is on a grid, so it is discrete.

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the paths are *progressive*: that means after every step you are closer than the previous step towards the target.  Take the difference $m=y_1-y_0$ and $n=x_1-x_0$. One has to make $m$ upward steps and $n$ rightward steps. (assuming for simplicity the target point is to the right and upward of initial point. By rotating axes and swapping initial and target point this can be achieved without affecting the answer). As steps are progressive no downward or leftward steps are allowed.

So this requires $m+n$ steps totally, out of which exactly $n$ of them have to be towards the right. We can schedule the path with rightward and upward steps in any order. Each will lead to one path.

So the answer is a binomial coefficient.

Comment: No the paths are not required to be progressive. If that was the case, the variable $L$ would be meanining less as $L$ would equal $m + n$. For example, there exist paths of length $7$ between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Comment: In that case there are infinitely many paths.  Suppose the least path is: , $A\to B\to C\to D$ Define a new path that  as $A\to B\to C\to B\to C\to D$. SO one can go back and forth between B and C any number of times leading to infinite number of paths.

Comment: All paths are self avoiding.

Comment: Moreover, the length is the finite constant $L$.